# How do i open these links using a script, im getting an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code i used:

```
import webbrowser
import time
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard


count = 0
urls = ['www.google.com','www.youtube.com']
k = PyKeyboard()
while count < 100:
for url in urls:
    webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
    time.sleep(10)
    k.press_keys(['Ctrl','w'])
    count = count + 1




else:
    pass
```

It shows no errors in my editor (visual studio code) but when i open it from both cmd AND directly from file explorer it does NOTHING.
PLEASE how do I fix this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your `pykeyboard` module from, could only find this [one](https://pypi.org/project/pykeyboard/) on PyPI and it doesn't let you press keys. I used `pyautogui` instead to have the keys pressed and it worked fine, check out [PyAutoGUI Documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you plan on using it.

Otherwise, your `for` loop needs to be indented, and the `else: pass` at the end is not needed. I'd also recommend using `count += 1` to increment instead of `count = count + 1` as it looks nicer.

Here's the code I used that worked both in Visual Studio and file explorer:

```
import webbrowser
import time
import pyautogui as py


count = 0
urls = ['www.google.com','www.youtube.com']
while count < 100:
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open(url, new=0)
        time.sleep(10)
        py.hotkey('ctrl','w')
        count += 1
```